# graphics.h library Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, bgi

I want to start writing code using functions from the graphics.h library in Code::Blocks.  After downloading, moving, and linking everything I'm still getting the error: "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" whenever I try to run any program that calls the graphics.h library.

```
#include<graphics.h>

int main()
{
int gd = DETECT;
int gm;
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

arc(200,200,0,130,50);

getch();
closegraph();
return 0;
}
```

This is just an example of what would return that error.  If I leave out all the functions it returns 0.

Comment: Code::Blocks is a tool that sits on top of a compiler, usually a gcc-based compiler. Please add to your question the version of this compiler `g++ -v`  on the command line should get this information for you. This is important because graphics.h is a relic of the 1980s. It was adapted to then-modern hardware Windows-based OSes around 2005. Well, it's been more than 10 years since then and time and tools have moved on. If you have a modern Code::Blocks install with a modern C++ compiler, odds are very good that it's not compatible with the winBGI library you are using.

Comment: If you are not required to use winBGI, may I recommend the graphics engines in [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)? Learning something up to date will be much more useful going forward.

Comment: Learn something that is useful in this generation, such as the graphics engines mentioned in the previous comments.  Learning winBGI is a dead-end.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is the usual Windows return code for Segmentation fault. (Seg. fault happens if you access an invalid address, e.g. a `NULL` pointer / `nullptr` on x86 CPUs.) I suspect that `initgraph()` failed, so that any further graphics command has undefined behavior. However, I agree with Paul: BGI is f***ing old. I already used it over 20 years ago when I was a student myself. ;-)